# RequestFactory process double jsr303 validation

Tags: hibernate, gwt, bean-validation, requestfactory

i'm using gwt with RequestFactory and i want to use JSR303 validation, but the problem is when i call a method using requestFactory like add(object o) it calls the validation for each field 2 times, for exemple, when i call save method for an object with a field annotated with a customized notnull annotation:

```
currentContext.add(toPersist).fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void response) {
        }
    });
```

my customized notnull annotation show the value that gonna be validated

```
public class NotEmptyValidator implements
    ConstraintValidator<NotEmpty, Object>{

@Override
public void initialize(NotEmpty constraintAnnotation) {

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    System.out.println("the value "+value);
    return  (value==null || value.toString().trim().equals("")) ? false:true;
}
```

}

i receive on the consol for the same field:

when i try to add a new entity:
[INFO] the value test
[INFO] the value test

when i try to modify an existing entity:
[INFO] the value test
[INFO] the value null

my question is why the validation is called 2 times, and why the value is null for the second time when i try a modification?

Comment: How to your annotated classes look like? Ae you using JPA as well?

Comment: Yes i'm using JPA and spring data, i have no problem with my junit test (server side)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the first time is on client side and the second time on the server side?

If yes, this would be correct because of security reasons.

Client side validation is to protected the client from makeing wrong inputs, server side validation is to protect your system from malicious attacks.

Comment: Sorry i edited my post the problem is when i try a modification the value is null, so the value is not modified

Comment: Can you post, how you edit your entity on client side please?

Comment: On the client sied im using gwt editors so the uiField are binded to valueProxy